# Deleting group of elements in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Event model and every event has user_id, and i want to delete all of them by one click.

```
 def destroy

    @events.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

I know that i need firstly to find all of them by user_id, but don't know how to delete than. Can someone help?

Comment: event has_many :users? is this your association?

Comment: tell us the association you have between Event and User.

Comment: @user123 nope,  event belongs_to :user, user has many events

Comment: To delete single Active record object You can use `@events.destroy` but To delete the collection of Active record object you have to use `@events.destroy_all`

Comment: so what do you want to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your user model have `has_many :events` Association if this is the case then you can try following.

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(1) # Or User.find(params[:user_id])
  @events = user.events.where(title: "FIRST")
  # Or If you just wanted to delete all Events except deleting user events then @events = Event.where(title: "FIRST")
  @events.destroy_all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: Good one. You don't have to create `@events` here though, seems unnecessary. It can be just `User.find(1).events.destroy_all` . :)

Comment: Yes I can but,  I have posted for her understanding.

Comment: How do you know it's him/her? By looking at their profiles? :P

Comment: What if i want destroy not only all event. I need to destroy for example  all events, where :title = 'FIRST'? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`destroy_all(conditions = nil)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class). Code would look something like this:

```
def destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    if Event.destroy_all(:user_id => params[:user_id])
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Events were successfully destroyed.' }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Events could not be deleted. Try again' }
    end
  end
end
```

Or instead of: `Event.destroy_all(:user_id => params[:user_id])`, if you have `User` object then you can do:

```
@user.events.destroy_all
```

Comment: What if i want destroy not only all event. I need to destroy for example  all events, where :title = 'FIRST'? Can you help?

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev : What did you mean by  `where :title = "FIRST"`? You can surely put any condition you like instead of `:user_id => params[:user_id]` or `@user.events.where(condition).destroy_all`.

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev I have edited my answer please check

Comment: i got undefined method destroy_all (

Answer (score 0):

- destroy(single object)/:destroy_all(for collection) The associated objects are destroyed alongside this object by calling their destroy method
- delete(single object)/:delete_all(for collection) All associated objects are destroyed immediately without calling their :destroy method

You can use any one of them according to your conditions

```
Event.destroy_all(conditions)
```

To destroy all methods with specific conditions.

Comment: So where this `options` are going finally ? :p

Comment: @AmitSharma Sure..  The comment was based on the before edit version. And here only the method names are mentioned.. On which object OP should call it ? With this answer, it is perfectly to ok the links in the comment section to point to the documentations.. What is being suggested by this line *You can use any one of them according to your conditions* ?

Comment: @AmitSharma Who wrote the answer ? Not you.. And why it has not been mentioned in the answer.. ?

Comment: @user123 You are new .. Remember answer should be pretty clean and acceptable.. Not like the one you did.. Please make it explicit..

Comment: @AmitSharma Come on.. Move on. This answer fits with comment not an answer. It is just re iteration of the documents words.. which can be done by specifying the links in the comments.. Or in answer with more explicitly..

Comment: What if i want destroy not only all event. I need to destroy for example  all events, where :title = 'FIRST'? Can you help?

Comment: @DamirNurgaliev I have edited my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.destroy_all(:user_id => params['user_id'])
or
Event.where(:user_id => id).destroy_all
```

This will destroy all events which belongs to that user_id